# C# - Como verifico se 2 arrays tem um ou mais números em comum?

Tags: c#, array

Como verifico que nos números de 4 TextBox que estão na array `numeros`, estão no array `impares` ou `pares`, quais são esses números e quantos são ímpares e quantos pares?

```
int[] numeros = new int[] {text_box1, text_box2, text_box3, text_box4};
int[] pares = new int[] {02, 04, 06, 08, 10};
int[] impares =  new int[] {01, 03, 05, 07, 09};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo estritamente os arrays de sua pergunta você pode usar o `Intersect` do Linq:

```
int[] numeros = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] pares = new int[] { 02, 04, 06, 08, 10 };
int[] impares = new int[] { 01, 03, 05, 07, 09 };

int[] inputsPares = numeros.Intersect(pares).ToArray();
int[] inputsImpares = numeros.Intersect(impares).ToArray();

int quantosPares = inputsPares.Length;
int quantosImpares = inputsImpares.Length;
```

Para o problema em questão, que consiste apenas em verificar se é par ou ímpar, você pode usar o operador mod, dessa forma não são necessários os arrays `pares` e `impares`.

```
int[] inputsPares = numeros.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToArray();
int[] inputsImpares = numeros.Where(x => x % 2 != 0).ToArray();
```